# grep + sed to replace characters surrounding a string

Tags: string, sed, grep

I'm looking to recurse through a folder and replace all occurences of `{{text in here}}` with `%{text in here}`

I checked the other grep+sed topics but they generally have to do with standard string replacement; I want to keep the string intact, but replace some characters *surrounding* the string (basically replacing the first opening brace with a `%` and removing the second closing brace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regexp like `s/{{\(.*\)}}/%{\1}/`

\1 in second string gets substituted with contents of first (...) pair

Comment: This will replace `{{abc}} def {{ghi}}` with `%{abc}} def {{ghi}`.

Comment: I actually found something that does exactly what I wanted (and the regular expression is the same as what you provided, though the solution was in ruby). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have to use `sed` for some reason, Perl is almost always preferable, due to its cleaner and much more powerful regex syntax:

```
find ... | xargs perl -i~ -pe 's/{{(.*?)}}/%{$1}/g'
```

Also, despite the fact that `-i~` creates a backup, I strongly recommend you backup your entire tree before playing around with this. I can't count the number of times I've wiped work by running a broken command-line twice. The most common error is accidentally using `-ne` instead of `-pe`, which results in all data being erased from the originals. Running it again replaces the backups with the newly-emptied files, leaving you with nothing but a sinking feeling in the pit of your stomach.

Comment: @kzh: On Linux/GNU, yes. On BSD/Mac, it's -E. This is another reason I prefer Perl.

Comment: The accepted answer does not work properly... As mentioned in the comments above. This one does.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
sed 's/{{/%{/g;s/}}/}/g' inputfile
```

or

```
sed 's/{{\([^}]*\)}}/%{\1}/g' inputfile
```

Comment: assuming (should be the case) that there is no `}` between `{{`and `}}`, so if Alex assume this, a realy simple and good solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary character to allow the exclusion (`[^³]`). This assume there are no  `³` and `²` inside. Nearly any other char could be use or secure this with a first check/substitution but often not needed on standard content.

```
sed -e 's/{{/²/g;s/}}/³/g;s/²\([^³]*\)³/%{\1}/g;s/²/{{/g;s/³/}}/g' YourFile
```

on KSH/posix sed

```
echo "{{abc}} def {{ghi}} jkl {{ mno } {{pqr}}" | sed -e 's/{{/²/g;s/}}/³/g;s/²\([^³]*\)³/%{\1}/g;s/²/{{/g;s/³/}}/g'

%{abc} def %{ghi} jkl %{ mno } {{pqr}
```

note the last encapsuled behavior on `{{ mno } {{pqr}}`